# Translated lens undistortion algorithm giving wrong results at corners

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, code-translation

I am trying to adapt the lens undistortion from [Oliver Kreylos' Kinect library](http://idav.ucdavis.edu/~okreylos/ResDev/Kinect/index.html) to Unity, but at the corners the vertices end up in the wrong positions for any radial distortion coefficients below about -0.15, give or take depending on the coefficient. The 2nd (k0), 4th (k1), and 6th (k2) order radial distortion coefficients are 0.091, -0.269, 0.094 respectively for my Kinect.

Here is the resulting mesh with k0 set to -0.18 and the rest to 0

[image: Lens undistortion with k0 set to -0.18, k1 and k2 set to 0]

Here is the undistortion function translated to C#

```
public Vector2 Undistort(Vector2 distorted)
{
    /*******************************************************************
    Must run two-dimensional Newton-Raphson iteration to invert the full
    distortion correction formula.
    *******************************************************************/

    /* Start iteration at the distorted point: */
    Vector2 p = distorted;
    for (int iteration = 0; iteration < undistortMaxSteps; ++iteration)
    {
        /* Calculate the function value at p: */
        Vector2 d = p - center;
        float r2 = d.sqrMagnitude;
        float div = 1 + (radialDistortion[0] + (radialDistortion[1] + radialDistortion[2] * r2) * r2) * r2;
        Vector2 fp = new Vector2(
            center[0] + d[0] * div + 2 * tangentialDistortion[0] * d[0] * d[1] + tangentialDistortion[1] * (r2 + 2 * d[0] * d[0]) - distorted[0],
            center[1] + d[1] * div + tangentialDistortion[0] * (r2 + 2 * d[1] * d[1]) + 2 * tangentialDistortion[1] * d[0] * d[1] - distorted[1]
            );

        /* Bail out if close enough: */
        if (fp.sqrMagnitude < undistortMaxError)
            break;

        /* Calculate the function derivative at p: */
        float[,] fpd = new float[2, 2];
        fpd[0, 0] = div + d[0] * (2 * radialDistortion[0] + (4 * radialDistortion[1] + 6 * radialDistortion[2] * r2) * r2) * d[0] + 2 * tangentialDistortion[0] * d[1] + 6 * tangentialDistortion[1] * d[0]; // d fp[0] / d p[0]
        fpd[0, 1] = d[0] * (2 * radialDistortion[0] + (4 * radialDistortion[1] + 6 * radialDistortion[2] * r2) * r2) * d[1] + 2 * tangentialDistortion[0] * d[0] + 2 * tangentialDistortion[1] * d[1]; // d fp[0] / d p[1]
        fpd[1, 0] = d[1] * (2 * radialDistortion[0] + (4 * radialDistortion[1] + 6 * radialDistortion[2] * r2) * r2) * d[0] + 2 * tangentialDistortion[0] * d[0] + 2 * tangentialDistortion[1] * d[1]; // d fp[1] / d p[0]
        fpd[1, 1] = div + d[1] * (2 * radialDistortion[0] + (4 * radialDistortion[1] + 6 * radialDistortion[2] * r2) * r2) * d[1] + 2 * tangentialDistortion[1] * d[0] + 6 * tangentialDistortion[0] * d[1]; // d fp[0] / d p[0]

        /* Perform the Newton-Raphson step: */
        float det = fpd[0, 0] * fpd[1, 1] - fpd[0, 1] * fpd[1, 0];
        p[0] -= (fpd[1, 1] * fp[0] - fpd[0, 1] * fp[1]) / det;
        p[1] -= (fpd[0, 0] * fp[1] - fpd[1, 0] * fp[0]) / det;
    }
```

`radialDistortion[]` is the k coefficients, `tangentialDistortion[]` is set to 0. `undistortMaxError` is 1.0e-32f, `undistortMaxSteps` is 20.

Input:

```
new Vector2((mx * kinectSize.x / (meshW - 1) - depthParams.principalPoint.x) / depthParams.focalLength.x,
            (my * kinectSize.y / (meshH - 1) - depthParams.principalPoint.y) / depthParams.focalLength.y);
```

resulting in input points from (-0.7013, -0.5808) to (0.7013, 0.5808)

I stepped through the code at some of the bad corners, and the loop seemed to diverge instead of converge on the correct result like the other points.

**Edit:** turns out I made a mistake when translating the `fpd` section. I used `radialDistortion` for a few variables when I should have used `tangentialDistortion`. Now it works for the specific values for my Kinect, but I still get some errors in the corners with larger coefficients. I have updated the code and question to reflect this